# Como criar um sistema de templates com slots/seções com PHP?

Tags: php, template

Estou com uma dúvida para fins de estudos. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto MVC e AJAX e, nas páginas que usaria Javascript, usaria esses delimitadores.

Código:

```
<?php $script->start('js'); :>
      <script> console.log("hellow Word")</script>
<?php $script->end(); ?>
```

Na pagina index dos meus estilos e script chamaria essa função abaixo dos scripts:

```
<?php $scripts->section('js'); ?> //execulta o codigo acima.
```

Comment: Você já tem mais ou menos uma ideia? Já fez algo? Eu já desenvolvi um [sistema de views em PHP](https://github.com/phplegends/view/tree/master/src), e para isso usei `ob_start`.

Comment: É importante fornecer um [mcve] para sua pergunta. Clique em [edit] e adicione mais informações. A pergunta está meio vaga...

Comment: achei uma referencia do que estou querendo explicar:
https://platesphp.com/templates/sections/
Obrigado

Comment: Exatamente o que eu disse. Você consegue utilizar a função `ob_start()`. Ela captura toda saída proveniente do código. Em seguida, você pode recuperá-la com `ob_get_end()`.

Comment: O que você quer na verdade é saber como trabalhar com sistema de "seções" em um template php.

Comment: Obrigado por me esclarecer minha duvida, poderia me da um exemplo simples ?

Comment: Olá, jovem. Fiz um exemplo bem simples pra você entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De maneira bem simples, imagino que você queira construir um sistema de layout e slots de template no PHP.

Há muito tempo atrás fiz uma lib chamada [PHPLegends/View](https://github.com/phplegends/view/tree/master/src) que tem isso.

Só que, de maneira bem simplificada, você pode fazer da maneira que vou explicar abaixo:

Crie a Classe `View`, que representa o template que vai ser renderizado.

```php
class View
{
    
    protected $sections    = [];
    protected $lastSection = null;
    protected $layout      = null;
    protected $data        = [];
    protected $filename    = null;

    public function __construct($filename, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getSection($name)
    {
        return $this->sections[$name] ?? null;
    }

    public function section($name)
    {
        ob_start();

        $this->lastSection = $name;
    }

    public function end()
    {

        $this->sections[$this->lastSection] = trim(ob_get_clean());

        $this->lastSection = null;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        extract($this->data);

        ob_start();

        require $this->filename;

        if ($this->layout) {
            require $this->layout;
        }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function layout($layout)
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }
}
```

Em seguida, você agora precisa de criar dois arquivos para fazer o teste. Crie o arquivo `templates/layout.php` e `templates/teste.php`. Com os seguintes conteúdos:

layout.php:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?= $this->getSection('title') ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?= $this->getSection('content') ?>

    <footer><?= $this->getSection('footer') ?></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

e teste.php

```php
<?php $this->layout('templates/layout.php') ?>

<?php $this->section('footer') ?>
Meu footer bonito
<?php $this->end() ?>

<?php $this->section('content') ?>
Olá, estou na sessão "content". Meu nome é <?= $nome ?> e tenho <?= $idade ?> anos.
<?= $this->end() ?>


<?php $this->section('title') ?>
Título do meu site
<?php $this->end() ?>
```

Em seguida, faça o teste chamando assim:

```php
$view = new View('templates/teste.php', [
    'nome' => 'Wallace',
    'idade' => 30,
]);

echo $view->render();
```

O resultado será:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Título do meu site</title>
</head>
<body>
    Olá, estou na sessão "content". Meu nome é Wallace e tenho 30 anos.
    <footer>Meu footer bonito</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

### Explicação

#### ob_start e ob_get_end

O segredo está no `ob_start()` e `ob_get_end()`. A primeira função captura para a memória tudo que está indo para saída (as coisas que você dá `echo` ou escreve como `html`). Em seguida, quando chamamos `ob_get_end` você obtém todo conteúdo armazenado e a captura é encerrada. Para facilitar, sempre pegamos o nome e colocamos na na variável `$sections` com uma chave e um valor capturado até a chamada de `end`.

Note que em `render` chamamos de novo o `ob_start()`. Isso é para o conteúdo de `require` não ser exibido, e sim apenas capturado. Mesmo você chamando `ob_start` várias vezes, é considerado apenas o trecho onde você chamou `ob_start` até a chamada de `ob_get_end`. O PHP internamente vai empilhando, até você "fechar" todos os `ob_start` com a chamada de `ob_get_end`.

Lembrando que esse exemplo foi o mínimo, apenas para entender o funcionamento. Você pode separar o código de forma melhor, se achar necessário, como fiz na minha biblioteca.

#### extract

Essa função transforma os valores passados num `array` em variáveis. Como usamos o `require` dentro do método `render`, as variáveis estarão disponíveis no seu "template".

Assim segundo, no nosso caso, o valor `['nome' => 'Wallace', 'idade' => 30]` foram transformados para `$nome` e `$idade`.

#### O acesso ao `$this`

Como nosso template foi chamado através da função `require`, tudo que tiver dentro da classe `View` estará acessível em `templates/layout.php` e `templates/teste.php`, inclusive a variável `$this`. Foi por esse motivo que na minha biblioteca eu criei a classe `Context`, para ela isolar o escopo dos templates para a instância de `Context`, já que tinha coisas em `View` que não queria que fosse acessíveis pelo template. Mas nesse caso, é só uma ideia, fica a seu critério implementar isso ou de outra forma.

> **NOTA**: O meu `section` é equivalente ao seu `start`, seguido de `end`. E o meu `getSection` é equivalente ao seu `section`. Pode ficar a vontade para mudar os nomes =)

Comment: Amigo Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda, vou estudar obrigado mas uma vez.